# Is $\big\{\frac{d(x,P_1)}{d(x,P_2)}=r\big\}$ a hypersphere in a normed space?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $P_1,P_2\in X$ be two different points. Pick $r>0$, $r\neq1$. Can we find a $C\in X$ and a $\rho>0$ such that
$$\bigg\{\frac{d(x,P_1)}{d(x,P_2)}=r\bigg\}=\{d(x,C)=\rho\}\quad?$$

In the Euclidean space with the standard inner product the result is true and follows trivially from the distance formula from the Pythagorean theorem. As Ted Shifrin pointed out in the comment, it is also trivially true for an inner product space.

Comment: "Coordinate formula for the circumference"??  It certainly works in any inner product space.

Comment: Well I don't know how to call it, I mean the standard formula that they teach you in high school...

Comment: You mean the distance formula (from the Pythagorean theorem), I guess. I just write it all out with dot (inner) product, so it certainly gives a hypersphere (not circle) in general, including Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Yes I mean the distance formula from the Pythagorean theorem, and yes I have been imprecise in the question: of course it is a circumference only in dimension $2$ while in general it is a hypersphere. I have now corrected this imprecision. I am also ok with the fact that the formula holds in any inner product space. What I want to know is if it also holds in a generic normed space.

Comment: If $P_1 = P_2$ the left set is $\{P_1\}$ which is not a sphere

Comment: @blamethelag Yes of course ; it should have been said that the points are different, but you will agree that it's not the most important "point":)

Comment: @blamethelag I've edited to exclude this case (which is, however, just a matter of definitions).

Comment: "In the case of finite dimensional vector spaces the result is true"  Really?  Try $\mathbb R^2$ with some norm such that the Pythagorean theorem fails.

Comment: A name I have not seen is "Apollonius circles" (and more generally Apollonius spheres)

Comment: @GEdgar I've edited. Your comment also answers the question, thanks.

Comment: To be more explicit, a counterexample should be given by the maximum norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarise the discussion in the comments so that this question can have an accepted answer: the answer is no and a counterexample is given by the maximum norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.